# Symfony FormEvents get errors

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I call to form every route, so instead of all the time to do :

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(UserType:class);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I call it from twig `UserRegister.html.twig`:

```
 {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Security:register')) }}
```

and the twig:

```
{% if form.vars['errors'] is not empty %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
{% endif %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_end(form)
```

on the control it's:

```
 public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('register', UserType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form->getData());
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app.homepage');
    }
    return $this->render('@site_forms/UserRegister.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

So what's the big problem?
on error it will show only the form!
the error should return this current page!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: i update the code

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are rendering only form's twig on `!isValid()` case. Maybe it comes from here?

you could use `$this->redirectToRoute($request->get('_route')` to always redirect to current page.

Comment: Please, tell if that was the problem.